# How can I get raw audio from a wav file?

Tags: java, audio, wav, decoding

I need to get the raw audio samples from a wav file, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: Would you settle for a way that works which is not necessarily "the best" ? There is a site dedicated to the usage of JavaSound which may hold the answer: http://www.jsresources.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I have found that the raw data can be extracted by jumping to the "data" part at the end of the header.

Answer (score 0):

Java has built in support for most .wav/.aiff files using the javax.sound.* classes:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
```

Read this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/open-electribe-editor/C5BDLbZMLJA